# Magento 2 data migration

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2.3.4, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

Good day to all the readers.

Is there any way to migrate data between two Magento 2?

I think that the data migration tool doesn't allow to do that.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**
*EXPLANATION:*
I have an old Magento 2.2.7 version and I have to migrate to a 2.3.4 version (not 2.4, for unexplained customer reasons) the new version contains a new theme and a completely different logic. I didn't start from the original database because I didn't have access to the production database when I started developing the theme.

Comment: you might wanna provide more context to this. Are you trying to build a new website based on other old website and have data migrated  old to new ?

Comment: @rex see the edit 1

Comment: if I have to upgrade magento 2.2 to 2.3 version - i would probably disable the customizations from theme in 2.2 disable custom modules (app/code) and upgrade it. and later I will update custom modules based what it will need, and at last i will compare theme overrides and update them. 
https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-upgrade.html#verify-zend-framework-composer-dependencies

Now in your case, you could do a dump of database and import in your working 2.3.4 env and see what happens, chances are there will be issues, but you can get them through one by one.

Comment: There isn't really a tool for magento 2.2 to 2.3 upgrade as far as i know. thus I recommend upgrade only magento without customizations and later update app/code modules and the theme etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using a third party extension, there's no native-way to do that.

Comment: please share extension

Comment: @PratikKamani with this: https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html

Answer (score 1):

you can export data to csv

- products
- customers
- orders

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/data-export.html

then using `google sheets` change it the way you need it, and import.

also there are lots of import/export extensions.

Answer (score 0):

can you tell us which extension that you used? thanks

Comment: With this extension: https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html